# Differentiating the sigmoid function using limits

Tags: derivatives

$$
f(x) =\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}
$$

The derivative of the above function is:

$$
{f}'(x) =\dfrac{e^{-x}}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}
$$

But when I try to use the definition of the derivative:

$$
h = \Delta x
$$

$$
{f}'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}
$$

My solution turned out this way:

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-(x+h)}} - \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1 + e^{-x}-(1 + e^{-(x+h)})}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) }}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1 + e^{-x}-1 - e^{-(x+h)})}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) }}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) }}{h}
$$

If $h \to 0$:

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{0}{(1 + e^{-x})^2 } = 0
$$

Where am I making a mistake to get to the result

$$
{f}'(x) =\dfrac{e^{-x}}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}
$$

Could you help me?

Comment: Note $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}}{h} = e^{-x}$

Comment: Ok, my mistake putting $ h^2 $, but how does this $ e^{-x}- e^{-x-h} $ become $ e^{-x} $, could you show me?

Comment: $e^{-x}-e^{-x-h} = e^{-x}(1-e^{-h})$. Do you know the limit of $(1-e^{-h})/h$ as $h$ goes to zero?

Comment: $e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}$ does not become $e^{-x}$ as $h \to 0$.  But$ \dfrac{{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}}{h}$ does; it is the derivative of $-e^{-x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer step by step, the way was to use L'Hopital's rule when there is an indeterminacy in the limit like $$ \frac{0}{0}  or  \frac{\infty}{\infty} $$

step by step:

$$
f(x) =\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}
$$

$$
h = \Delta x
$$

$$
{f}'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-(x+h)}} - \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1 + e^{-x}-(1 + e^{-(x+h)})}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) }}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1 + e^{-x}-1 - e^{-(x+h)})}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) }}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) }}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x}) } \cdot\dfrac{1}{h}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} \cdot\dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x})}
$$

Here we have an indeterminacy:

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} = \dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-0}}{0} =  \dfrac{0}{0}
$$

So we can use L'Hopital's rule differentiating each function:

$$
\dfrac{d}{dh} \left(e^{-x} - e^{-x-h}\right) = \dfrac{d}{dh} (e^{-x}) - \dfrac{d}{dh} (e^{-x-h}) = 0 + e^{-x-h} = e^{-x-h}
$$

$$
\dfrac{d}{dh} (h) = h = 1
$$

$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dh} \left(e^{-x} - e^{-x-h}\right)}{\dfrac{d}{dh} (h)} = \dfrac{e^{-x-h}}{1}
$$

Substitute by zero

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} =  \dfrac{e^{-x-0}}{1}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} =  e^{-x}
$$

We do the distributive on the denominator:

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x})}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x} + e^{-(x+h)} + e^{-(x+h)}\cdot e^{-x}}
$$

We simplify:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x} + e^{-x-h} + e^{-2x-h}}
$$

we can substitute for 0 that will not occur indetermination:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x} + e^{-x-0} + e^{-2x-0}}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x} + e^{-x} + e^{-2x}}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{1 + 2e^{-x} + e^{-2x}}
$$

Factoring the denominator

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}
$$

Conclusion:

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^{-x}- e^{-x-h}}{h} \cdot\dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-(x+h)})\cdot (1 + e^{-x})}
$$

$$
=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{1} \cdot \dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}
$$

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-(x+h)}} - \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}}{h} = \dfrac{e^{-x}}{(1 + e^{-x})^2}
$$